# SQL - Insert all dates within range from table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to populate a table with dates, based upon values contained within another.

```
Source : tblA
dtFrom       dtTo
2019-01-01   2019-01-03
2019-02-01   2019-02-02
2019-03-01   2019-03-01

Destination : tblB
sDate
2019-01-01
2019-01-02
2019-01-03
2019-02-01
2019-02-02
2019-03-01
```

SQL Server 2014. As always, thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select dtfrom as dt, dtto
      from tblA
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dt), dtto
      from dates
      where dt < dtto
    )
insert tblB (sDate)
select distinct dt
from dates;
```

The `select distinct` is only necessary to handle overlapping periods.  If you know there are no overlaps, then don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` to combine values from both columns into one rowset:

```
insert  tblB
        (sDate)
select  distinct dt
from    (
        select  dtFrom as dt
        from    tblA
        union all
        select  dtTo
        from    tblA
        ) s
```

Comment: thanks - but I'm looking to insert every date within the selected date range, not just split out the date range

Comment: @BigIWT, please edit your question to include that requirement, it is not clear as stated.

Comment: Aha, see Gordon Linoff's answer which does just that

Answer (score 0):

Use the always handy [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/), which is a table that holds 1 row for each day, for all days between specific years. You can add additional columns like `IsBusinessDay` or `WorkingStartHour` / `WorkingEndHour` to make your date queries much easier.

```
-- Create Calendar Table
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2000-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2050-01-01'

SET DATEFIRST 1 -- 1: Monday, 7: Sunday

CREATE TABLE CalendarTable (
    Date DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    IsWorkingDay BIT
    -- Other columns you might need
    )

;WITH RecursiveCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Date = @StartDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, R.Date)
    FROM
        RecursiveCTE AS R
    WHERE
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, R.Date) <= @EndDate
)
INSERT INTO CalendarTable (
    Date,
    IsWorkingDay)
SELECT
    Date = R.Date,
    IsWorkingDay = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, R.Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
    RecursiveCTE AS R
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Now with your calendar table, just join with a `BETWEEN` and `INSERT` to your destination table. You can use `DISTINCT` to make sure dates don't repeat:

```
INSERT INTO tblB (
    sDate)
SELECT DISTINCT
    sDate = C.Date
FROM
    tlbA AS A
    INNER JOIN CalendarTable AS C ON C.Date BETWEEN A.dtFrom AND A.dtTo
```

Let's say for example that you only want to insert records that are working days (monday to friday). You just need to filter the calendar table and done. You can add whichever logic you want on your table and just filter it when using, without repeating complex datetime logics.

```
INSERT INTO tblB (
    sDate)
SELECT DISTINCT
    sDate = C.Date
FROM
    tlbA AS A
    INNER JOIN CalendarTable AS C ON C.Date BETWEEN A.dtFrom AND A.dtTo
WHERE
    C.IsWorkingDay = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With a Calendar you can inner join on the ranges to produce an Insert statement.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(dtFrom) FROM tblA)
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(dtTo) FROM tblB)
;WITH Calendar as 
( 
    SELECT CalendarDate = @StartDate, CalendarYear = DATEPART(YEAR, @StartDate), CalendarMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, @StartDate) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CalendarDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CalendarDate), CalendarYear = DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate), CalendarMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, CalendarDate) 
    FROM Calendar WHERE DATEADD (MONTH, 1, CalendarDate) <= @EndDate 
) 

INSERT INTO tblB
SELECT DISTINCT
    C.CalendarDate
FROM
    Calendar C
    INNER JOIN tblA A ON C.CalendarDate BETWEEN A.dtFrom AND A.dtTo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result by using the below queries.

**Steps 1 - Create a Custom Function which will take date range as a parameter and will return date series.**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GenerateDateRange]
(@StartDate AS DATE,
 @EndDate AS   DATE,
 @Interval AS  INT
)
RETURNS @Dates TABLE(DateValue DATE)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CUR_DATE DATE
    SET @CUR_DATE = @StartDate
    WHILE @CUR_DATE <= @EndDate BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES(@CUR_DATE)
        SET @CUR_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, @Interval, @CUR_DATE)
    END
    RETURN;
END;
```

**Step 2 - Join this custom function with your table tblA and insert the record in tblb as needed**

```
insert tblb
select b.* from tblA a cross apply dbo.GenerateDateRange(a.dtFrom, a.dtTo, 1) b
```